# Why won't gedit file browser plugin show files?

Tags: windows-explorer, plugins, gedit

Does anyone know why gedit won't show any files on my system, but only show folders? See attached screenshot for clarification. In the screenshot, both Explorer and gedit are showing the exact same location, but none of the files are showing in gedit file browser.

How can it be solved?

[image]

P.S. If it matters, I'm running Server 2008 R2.

Comment: @r0ca (who added tags): why is the tag "browser" in this question...

Comment: I changed it for Windows Explorer. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I was not able to Google correct answer. I did another tries and this one solved my problem:

1. Right click in the gedit filebrowser pane
2. Hover mouse over "Filter" option in the pop-up menu
3. Check "Show Binary" option

This helped on my computer with gedit + Windows Vista. The "Show Binary" option affected all files, not only the binary files. The text files were also affected.

Hope this will help.

PS: I give no warranty at all.

Comment: if anyone from gedit is listening please make this the default!